# Why does my iOS app crash when trying presentModalViewController?

Tags: ios, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've been banging my head against this all day, it seems like something simple but I can't figure it out.

I've got an iOS app that I created using the "View-based Application" template in XCode. Here is essentially the code I have:

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MainViewController *viewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MainViewController *viewController;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window, viewController;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

MainViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
}
-(IBAction) button:(id)sender;
@end
```

MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "ModalViewController.h"
@implementation MainViewController
...
-(IBAction) button:(id)sender {
    ModalViewController *mvc = [[[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([ModalViewController class]) bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
}
@end
```

There's nothing of interest in the ModalViewController.

So the modal view should display when the button is pressed. When I press the button, it hangs for a second then crashes back to the home screen with no error message.

I am stumped, please show me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Why don't you look at the compiler output and see why it is crashing? It usually would give you a reason there.

Answer (score 0):

> There's nothing of interest in the ModalViewController.

Although there may not be anything of interest, there could still be something causing the problem.

Does your View Controller override the function loadView?

A problem that has got me a few times is if you don't call [super loadView]; first in your overriden loadView method. Not doing this causes a crash when moving into that View Controller.

Good luck in trying to solve this one!

N

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I followed your advice but the problem is still happening. I'm sure it is a little thing like this that I am missing.

Comment: Yes - it often is something small! I'm sorry my tip didn't help! If you're using XIB files to layout your views, there could also be something wrong in there. Anyway - good luck in finding out what's wrong!